# converting String to XML doc in java

Tags: java, xml, string

Hello I have generated XML content as string. But I have to convert string to XML data type.

```
String str = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Message><Rc1>12343322</Rc1><Rc2>125145552</Rc2><Rc3>54682242</Rc3><Rc4>7777332287</Rc4></Message>"
```

How can I convert this string to `xmldoc` type?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you trying to use the W3C API in Java? Have you looked up XML tutorials? Note that "1234...287" is not XML...

Comment: I written but it did dot seem proper.  Suppose that it is proper xml

Comment: Well, that's now not a valid string literal. But okay, assuming you have a String which *does* contain valid XML... what have you tried so far? There are *lots* of tutorials on the web for parsing XML in Java. You should do research before asking a question - and if you *have* done research and *have* tried something, but it's not working, provide sample code and explain what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
  String xmlStr = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Message><Rc1>12343322</Rc1>     <Rc2>125145552</Rc2><Rc3>54682242</Rc3><Rc4>7777332287</Rc4></Message>"
 DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
  DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  
  Document doc = builder.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( xmlStr ) ) );
```